# The root of $x=5-5e^{-x}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x=5-5e^{-x}$ where $x\in \mathbb {R}$.

The first root $x_1=0$. But there was also another root $x_2>0$.
How to find it without computational solution, for example, through analysis?

Comment: You can write the positive root as $W(-5e^{-5})+5$ where $W$ is the Lambert-W function. However, to resolve this value, you need to compute $W$ at a particular point (e.g., by Newton's method). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to find a solution without numerical methods.
From the graph, it's clear that the solution you're seeking is close to $x=5$. If you start a Newton-Raphson iteration at $x=5$, you will get a solution that's accurate to about 15 decimal places in 3 or 4 iterations. If you're using floating point arithmetic on a computer or a calculator, a solution given by a formula would not be any more accurate than this.

Here is the graph:

[image]

You can use Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha to compute an answer that's accurate to as many decimal places as you want, but this still a numerical solution, of course.